# The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update must be equal to before the update

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've a  UICollectionView that contains 10 sections and each sections have 2 cells.
I am trying to delete a cell but I am getting this:

```
The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (2)
```

This is how I remove:

```
NSUInteger arrayLength = 1;
    NSUInteger integerArray[] = {0,0};
    NSIndexPath *aPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:integerArray length:arrayLength];
    [self.collectionFavs deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aPath]];
```

I just want to delete a cell or section with the cells. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delete element from datasource array.
F.e. if your method return 2 before deleting cell then after deleting it should return 1

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (notdeleted)
        return 2;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

In fact if you return [array count] in this method, then you should remove 1 object from array before calling -deleteItemsAtIndexPaths

```
NSUInteger integerArray[] = {0,0};
NSIndexPath *aPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:integerArray length:arrayLength];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[self.collectionFavs deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aPath]];
```

Comment: it's working now... Thank you very much @Jackos. But this is removes a section, it is possible to remove just a cell inside a section?

Comment: It's strangely. You have two methods in datasource protocol: – collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: and – numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:. First used for set number of cells in some section, second need for set number of sections. Maybe you remove object from wrong array? :)

Comment: I've 10 sections and each sections have 2 cells. I want to remove each cell individually but when every cell is removed in a section then I want to remove this section too.

Comment: You can check count of cells in section. If it became 0, then you should use - (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections method and in -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView you should return new section count. F.e. in yours case after deleting section you should return 9 instead of 10.

Comment: I made it.. thank you for your helps.. I have another question :) how can I remove all objects in the collection? I removed everything in data source but i'm getting this : "attempt to delete section 2147483647, but there are only 2 sections before the update'"